# I get single quote instead of apostrophe in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python, wget

I have a python script that performs a `wget` request on a URL with `subprocess` module and I use the output with a regex to catch the name of the actual downloaded file. I had the problem that my regex did not work because it had apostrophe inside (ordinal 39) but the `wget`'s output had a left single quote (ordinal 8216) and a right singe quote (ordinal 8217).

My python script was running in a virtual environment (pipenv) in two different Ubuntu machines. One had the apostrophe in the output, and one had the single quotes.

My questions are, is this due to the terminal's config? Which settings in particular? `locale charmap` gives me `UTF-8` on both machines. Could it be because of the virtual environment (although they are the same)?

Comment: It probably depends on the language being used, and wget's version.